# How to validate a zip structure from S3 using AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

1. Using Java code I am creating a zip file
2. Then we are uploading the zip file to AWS S3 using a different web service/ web application
3. Now I want to validate if the zip contains certain folders to validate the expected zip structure.
4. Currently, I am uploading the zip file to my application server, then validating the zip structure and after validation uploading to S3
5. What I want is to upload the zip directly to S3 without validation.
6. Next, I like to trigger a lambda function and in the lambda function I like to verify the zip structure

Question:-

Is it possible to download a zip file lambda from S3 for processing?
A zip file size can be more than 1 GB

Answer (score 0):

These are the main zip limis of aws lambda

1. Lambda function deployment package size (compressed .zip/.jar
   file)-**50 MB**
2. Size of code/dependencies that you can zip into a deployment package
   (uncompressed .zip/.jar size). - 250 MB

Note

Each Lambda function receives an additional 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory. The /tmp directory can be used for loading additional resources like dependency libraries or data sets during function initialization.

More details check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to download/load a whole big file to a single lambda function as it only have 1Gb of memory and 512Mb of temp disk space

Your solution should be dependent on the specific requirement ( how many file do you expect , is it constant workload or not, do you need it to scale very heavy workload... )

In the case you want to upload the file to S3 first before doing anything, this is one of the way I can think of

- Spawn an EC2 instance with EBS. Set it up as shared drive ( note :  The larger drive, the better IOPS performance )
- Leverage the [S3 support for Range request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html), use Lambda download the file as multiple part and join them on the shared drive
- Create another lambda function to validate the file created on shared drive, then delete it.

Depend on your workload you can use provisioned IOPS drive, some method to throttle ( maybe SQS )

Regarding the issue of limited memory and disk space. I think many people are on the same boat with you

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179785